# How to filter array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

Here is my input :

```
const data = [
  { group: [{ label: "Can View" }, { label: "Can Create" }] },
  { topgroup: [{ label: "Can View" }, { label: "Can Create" }] },
  { emptyGorup: [] }
];
```

I am converting array of object to object by using this code

method 1 :

```
let permissions =
  data &&
  data.reduce((a, b) => {
    const onlyKey = Object.keys(b)[0];
    a[onlyKey] = b[onlyKey].map(i => i.value);
    return a;
  }, {});
```

```
//Output : {group:["can view","can create"],topgroup:["can view","can create"],emptygroup:[]}
```

My question is that I don't want to get object property if Object property is empty []. For example, In my output, I can see object property emptygroup is [].

```
 {emptygroup:[]}.
```

My expected output will be if emptygroup is []

```
//Output : {group:["can view","can create"],topgroup:["can view","can create"]}
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: So data and permissionData are the same right?

Comment: I just edited now

Comment: why is "can create" not in `group` (your expected output) when `group` has an object with the `label` of "can create"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking the length of the array

```js
const permissionData = [
  { group: [{ label: "Can View" }, { label: "Can Create" }] },
  { topgroup: [{ label: "Can View" }, { label: "Can Create" }] },
  { emptyGorup: [] }
];

let permissions =
  permissionData &&
  permissionData.reduce((a, b) => {
    const onlyKey = Object.keys(b)[0];
    if(b[onlyKey].length) {
      a[onlyKey] = b[onlyKey].map(i => i.label);
    }
    return a;
  }, {});
  
console.log(permissions)
```

Comment: can you look this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829455/how-to-filtering-array-of-objects-to-another-array-of-objects-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment107622910_60829455

Answer (score 2):

You can extend your current code. After you get the object you can filter out the key with empty array using filter and build object again from filtered values

```js
let obj = {
  group: ["can view"],
  topgroup: ["can view", "can create"],
  emptygroup: []
}

let finalObj = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => Array.isArray(value) && value.length))

console.log(finalObj)
```

Comment: can you look this ? I am trouble to solve this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829455/how-to-filtering-array-of-objects-to-another-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can add a condition in reduce:

```
let permissions =
  permissionData &&
  permissionData.reduce((a, b) => {
    const onlyKey = Object.keys(b)[0];
    if (a[onlyKey]) {
      a[onlyKey] = b[onlyKey].map(i => i.value);
    }
    return a;
  }, {});
```